# Special character password variable from bash to expect block is not working

Tags: command-line, bash, password, special-characters, expect

I have been struggling with this issue for a few days now. I have scoured the internet for a solution and tried many different methods but none seems to be fruitful so far. I am passing a password variable which contains special characters to expect block and it always error out at the password.

Here's my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
server_List=("MySQLServer1" "MySQLServer2")
osUser='mysql'
osUserPwd='H3htg#41fRth!'
newRootPass='prnH4xRJSMwbWn9ht!M5t'
oldRootPwd='prnH4x^JSMwbWn9h!M6J'
    for host in ${server_List[@]}
      do
        echo "Processing host $host"
        /usr/bin/expect -c '
        spawn ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" '$osUser'@'$host';
        expect "password: "
        send "'$osUserPwd'\r"
        expect "$ "
        send -- "mysqladmin --user root -p password '$newRootPass'"
        expect "Enter password: "
        send -- "'$oldRootPwd'\r"
        expect "$ "
        send "exit\r" '
    done
```

Here's the Error:

```
[mysql@centralserver myself]$ ./test2.sh
Processing host MySQLServer1
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking no mysql@MySQLServer1
Password:
Last login: Tue Jan 24 10:00:43 2023 from 10.14.20.18
[mysql@MySQLServer1 ~]$ mysqladmin --user root -p password prnH4xRJSMwbWn9ht!M5tprnH4x^JSMwbWn9h!M6J
-bash: !M5tprnH4x: event not found
```

I would appreciate if someone can point me where I am making the mistake.

Comment: Try to use _here documents_ for the `expect` command. Replace the `'` with `<<EOT` in the `expect` command, remove `'` from the end of the last `send` command, and add a line that starts with `EOT` in the first column after that last `send` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your shell variables are *unquoted* in the shell. That allows the shell to perform various substitutions

Instead of

```
send "'$osUserPwd'\r"
```

you have to do

```
send "'"$osUserPwd"'\r"
# .....^..........^
```

---

Alternately, instead of composing the expect code as a string piece-by-piece, pass the shell variables though the environment:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash
server_List=("MySQLServer1" "MySQLServer2")
osUser='mysql'
osUserPwd='***'
newRootPass='***'
oldRootPwd='***'
export osUser osUserPwd newRootPass oldRootPwd host

for host in "${server_List[@]}"     # <= quoted
do
    echo "Processing host $host"
    /usr/bin/expect << 'END_EXPECT'   # a quoted heredoc
        spawn ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" $env(osUser)@$env(host)
        expect "password: "
        send "$env(osUserPwd)\r"
        expect "$ "

        # Need to send literal quotes for the password on the mysqladmin
        # command below: this prevents the remote shell from altering
        # the password on the command line.
        # Don't forget \r to hit enter.
        send -- "mysqladmin --user root -p password '$env(newRootPass)'\r"
        expect "Enter password: "
        send -- "$env(oldRootPwd)\r"
        expect "$ "
        send "exit\r"
        expect eof     # <= gracefully wait for the ssh connection to end
END_EXPECT
done
```

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed explanation and the answer, I tried your suggestion but still getting the same error:

[mysql@MySQLServer1 ~]$ mysqladmin --user root -p password "prnH4xRJSMwbWn9ht!M5t"
-bash: !M5t: event not found

As you can see the password is now being passed quoted properly but bash is erroring out.

Comment: Having eliminated the outer single quotes (by using a here-document to read the expect script from stdin rather than a `-c ' ... '` argument string), you can single-quote the password(s) I think? i.e. `'$env(newRootPass)'` in place of `\"$env(newRootPass)\"`. That should prevent history expansion in the remote shell.

Comment: Good call! @Ali on the "send mysqladmin" line, note the single quotes.

Comment: Thank you everyone, it works now.

Comment: @glennjackman Any suggestion on how I can hide the passwords in the above script? When I go to the target servers' history where the root passwords was updated it shows the password string on all of them which defeats the purpose of rotating password :).

Comment: You can't. The script is a text file that other people can (probably) read. The typical advice is "never store passwords in a plaintext file". You can _obscure_ the password, but the script will need to **unobscure** them, and people can read all about exactly how you do that. You might want to investigate using a password manager and use that tool's API to store and retrieve passwords more securely. Even that approach won't be able to be completely automated because you'll need to enter a master password.

Comment: @glennjackman I meant to say when the password is provided in the foreach loop when it spawns the ssh and then change password on each mysql server. Is there a way I can hide the password at that moment from being displayed in the history? e.g. read password -s

Comment: I was able to do this by passing -s flag in my update password command: send -- "mysqladmin --user root -p password -s '$env(newRootPass)'\r"